# Logisim - Tunnel that outputs the OR result of all of its inputs

Tags: digital-logic, simulation

Consider this screenshot: 
 [image]

When the two values differ, I get this:
[image]

This makes sense, but it's a problem. I would like the tunnel to function like this: when it's getting mixed values, it outputs the OR result of the values instead of an error value. So, in the case of the above image, the tunnel's output would be '1'. Will I have to spam OR gates and a bunch of different tunnels to do this, or is there a built in tool/plugin I can use to do it for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Logisim, a tunnel is just a hidden wire — all tunnels with the same name (in this case, "Tunnel"), are effectively connected together.

When you try to force two instances of the same tunnel to different values, anything that tries to evalulate the value (including a third tunnel) will show an error.

To create a new signal that is a logical OR of one or more existing signals, you need to instantiate an actual [OR gate](http://ozark.hendrix.edu/~burch/logisim/docs/2.3.0/libs/gates/basic.html).